# Flutter: What is the life cycle of Provider state management?

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, lifecycle, flutter-provider

Like in GetX, we have onInit(), onReady(), onClose() methods inside GetxController.
but in provider which extends ChangeNotifier doesn't have those methods.

so basically i have to use stateful widgets for init's and for other initializations.

So just wanted to know exactly the states of Provider.

Answer (score 1):

Provider does not work as Gets Work. It uses flutter state life cycle.
you can understand like that:

1. Initialise provider at Starting of App
2. Create a class which extends Change Notifier
3. To fetch value- create instance of provider or use Consumer at You Widget

For Better understanding you can follow this Link:https://github.com/Code-With-Patel/Provider.git